# Division in python3

Tags: floating-point, python-3.7, division

```
>>> 1/(2/3)
>>> 1.5
```

Why is the result rounded down to 1.5?  With python3, isn't the float displayed as 1.500?

Comment: 1.5 and 1.500 are the same number. Are you asking why the result is 1.5 rather than some other number (a question about how floating-point arithmetic works) or why “1.5” is displayed rather than “1.500” (a question about how numbers are formatted for display)?

Comment: Can you explain why you were expecting `"1.500"`? (Why three places after the point in particular? Why not four, or two, or ...)

Comment: If I calculate this, answer is 1.50000015.....I mean answer is not indivisible. So why answer is stopping just 1.5.

Comment: @鴨井千紗: I think you're asking why `1/(2/3)` gives *exactly* `1.5`, rather than a close approximation to `1.5`. Is that right?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes. Tell me why ?

Answer (score -2):

## python will display the answer to the 16 decimal places.

## for example:

```
print (1/3)
```

## this statement displays the following output # "0.3333333333333333".

Comment: If the float is more than the required decimal places, then python will round it off, otherwise python will print just the decimals not the extra zeros.

Comment: hope you like my answer.

Comment: Where in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) does it say that Python will display the answer to 16 decimal places? In the case OP asks about, [only one decimal place is shown in this Python implementation](https://onlinegdb.com/rkfbJAOTU). So how does this answer answer the question?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Nowhere. It's not a Python language guarantee (and it wouldn't make sense to make it a language guarantee), and it's not true in CPython or in any other Python implementation that I'm aware of. This answer is not useful.

Comment: I use python 3 and whenever I use float data type my answer is displayed upto a maximum of 16 decimal places. If the number has less than 16 decimal places, the answer is displayed to the appropriate number of decimal places. That is what he asked.

Comment: @FarisFahar: Try 1/6, or 1/7, or 3/7, or 2/11, or 5/11, or 3/13, or (many many other examples) on your machine and tell me how many digits after the decimal point you see. It won't be 16. (On my machine, `1/7` gives `0.14285714285714285`, which has 17 digits after the point, and I'd be quite surprised if yours gave a different result.) But even if your statement were correct, it *still* doesn't help answer the original question.

Comment: I think my answer addresses his question. He asked why is the result showing 1.5 instead of 1.500000000 and so on. I answered that the answer, if exact to a fixed number of decimal places, will be displayed as it is. If a value has decimal places above a certain limit ( its 16 on my computer), then the number will be rounded to the maximum decimal places.

Comment: No, it really _isn't_ 16 on your computer. Like I said, try `1/7` and tell me what you see.

Comment: I donot see how I haven't answered his question. If you can still find any shortcomings, educate me @Mark Dickinson

Comment: Ok. its 17 decimal places. What is your explanation?